# AWS LoadBalancer CNAME Hide

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Is this possible to hide the AWS classic/Application Load-balancer `CNAME`?

I have a domain name mapped to the AWS Classic load-balancer. 
When I did dig the domain name using host command it is showing the `loadbalancertype.amazonaws.com(CNAME)`.

I want to hide/remove the `CNAME` of the load-balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use CNAME entries?
You could use A Record Alias and then select your load-balancer as target. 
It also does reduce your cost for Route53.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

Then you will have ip addresses in your dig top level statement. However, if you go deeper by doing `host ip-address` you will get the domain `ec2-...compute.amazonaws.com` returned.

`airbnb.com` does it like that for example.

Answer (score 0):

AWS classic/Application Loadbalancer provides DNS name because it can scale up and scale down and you don't need to take care of adding IP addresses to your record. If you're using DNS service other then Route53 or CloudFlare , you don't have any option other then publishing CNAME record. In Route53, you have Alias record which can achieve your task but you need to use Route53 Nameservers for that, There is no problem in using CNAME Records, if you want no one can access our website using ELB DNS Name, you can have WAF rule to block based on HOST header.